# How do I update state in one component and have it reflected in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to React but I want to make sure that I am doing things properly and in accordance with best practice.
I am trying to create a Wait List. I have it broken down into sections.
My main component that is rendering the entire thing is structured as follows:

```
function Home() {

    const [waitList, setWaitList] = React.useState(WAITLIST);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Header />
                <OnDeck someState={waitList} />
                <MainList />
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

The Header has a title for the page and some buttons. The AddRow component is a button with a modal and a form to capture a persons info to add them to the waitlist.

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <h1>Wait List</h1>
                </Col>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <h1>1 Hour and 30 Minutes</h1>
                </Col>  
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <div>
                    <AddRow />
                    <Button 
                        size="sm"
                        className="btnCust"
                    >
                        Next
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Row>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

If I want the AddRow component to be able to add people to the waitlist, do I need to pass the state into that component?

It seems to me that the Home component is the "highest level of state" for this app. If I modify state in the AddRow component, will that update the table in the MainList component as well? (assuming that the state is being passed to that component as well)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried using a function to create an HTML element ('tr') and then adding the form values to it using a string. Then I added the new element to the table with the document.getElementById('mainTable') function. This worked, but I know it is not the "correct" way to do it. It also doesn't update the state of the waitlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Home() {

    const [waitList, setWaitList] = React.useState(WAITLIST);

    const addToWaitList = (item) => {
      // code goes here
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Header />
                <OnDeck someState={waitList} />
                <MainList />
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
<Header addToWaitList={addToWaitList} />
```

```
const Header = ({ addToWaitList }) => {
  return (
    // ...
    <AddRow onAdd={addToWaitList} />
    // ...
  )
}
```